# Разместить TableLayout по центру экрана

Tags: android, java

Как разместить TableLayout сеткой кнопок 5 на 5 по центру экрана?

Answer (score 1):

android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

Answer (score 1):

Могу ошибаться, но, по-моему, для этих целей лучше подходит `GridLayout`.

Comment: вот решение которую подсказали в stackoverflow с помощью RelativeLayout
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11206602/tablelayout-placing